# What is the best way/practice to list titles of the months (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the best way/practice to include the titles of the months in html if you are making Angularjs project?

here is snippet of the ugly hard-code that I want to make better:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">{{name}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="col-xs-1">Jan</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Feb</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Mar</div>
                            ...
            <div class="col-xs-1">Dec</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPD:** I need it for the table header in my `modules/report.html`.

Comment: Can't answer this without more detail about how you want to use them or what higher level problem you are trying to solve. All we can do is guess which is not productive for you or us

Answer (score 0):

I'ld do it like this:
In your context js, add an array or a function returning an array like that

```
monthlist = function(){
   return ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',  'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']}
```

Then, in your HTML you could do this:

```
<div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="col-xs-12">{{name}}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="col-xs-1" ngFor="month in monthlist()">{{month}}</div>

</div>
</div>
```

If you need a way without writing the Array yourself, I found this. https://jsfiddle.net/dstorey/Xgerq/ (edit: forgot link). I think it should be possible to make this fit your needs.

Answer (score -2):

The best practice is to use ui-calendar dependency like this:
To install:- bower install --save angular-ui-calendar

```
<div ui-calendar ng-model="eventSources"></div>

var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.calendar'])

$scope.eventSources = [];
```

Comment: why is installing a whole module for what could be a very simple use case a "best practice"? You are simply guessing at what OP is trying to accomplish

Comment: Because we don't know the purpose so I thought using ui-calendar would be the best idea.

Comment: It perhaps might be one idea....but if we don't know then how could it be "best"? If there isn't enough information given...and you have to do a lot of guessing...then don't answer the question and wait for clarification or vote to close because this question won't have any future value as it stands